# RAID - What happens if I import foreign configuration from newly inserted disk into an exisitng raid

Tags: raid, dell, raid10

Does the existing RAID fail if I import the foreign configuration from newly insert disk?

Say I have a `RAID 10` with 4 drives and I insert the 5th drive and its in Foreign state. Does it destroy my working RAID if I import foreign configuration?

What if I have a 8 Drives where only 4 DISK is used for RAID 10. 5th disk is hot spare, 6th DISK in ready state, 7th and 8th DISK in Foreign state. What happens if I import the 7th and 8th DISK in Foreign state? Would it create a secondary raid or destroy existing RAID? I think the right thing is to clear the Foreign state (i think?) on the 7th and 8th DISK so it becomes READY state.

Just wanted to understand the disaster behind it.

Answer (score 0):

If this is hardware RAID controller - I suppose it won't destroy any RAID on importing configuration. This can be tricky, but I got lot of RAID controllers and importing always mean adding. That means importing configuration will add new logical volume, which is described on newly inserted one.

Comment: any idea what's in the foreign configuration? How could it add a logical volume into an existing raid when it is already setup. And if its get added, does the new data gets written into it? Any good article links to learn about it more?

Comment: As for documentation you should consult RAID controller manual. About "logical volume" which will be added - if it is not a disk array system logical volume and RAID set are the same thing. So I assume you already have RAID set and logical volume and importing configuration will just read information from new disk and create new RAID set and new logical volume. New - means new for this particular controller at this point of time. RAID controller have all configurations in its NVRAM, it is also written on disks. If NVRAM contents and disks contents are not the same - controller need attention.

Comment: You can know what's in configuration only importing it. You always can enter configuration utility and manage this new configuration before machine is booting so it is safe.